# Why is Lua reporting that "The specified procedure could not be found." for this library compiled from source?

Tags: lua

I've been working at this for a while now and I can't figure out what's wrong.

At this point I've built everything from source and it still doesn't work. My environment is Windows 10 x64 and I'm compiling with Cygwin's MinGW-w64. Everything is compiled as i686 (32-bit) and not x86_64.

For reference, instances where I use `gcc` is actually `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`. `liblua53.dll.a` and `libyaml.a` were compiled from source using Lua 5.3.5 and LibYAML 0.2.2.

I built the objects:

```
gcc -DVERSION=\"git-5695363\" -Ilua-5.3/src -Ilibyaml/src/include -c ext/yaml/emitter.c -o emitter.o
gcc -DVERSION=\"git-5695363\" -Ilua-5.3/src -Ilibyaml/src/include -c ext/yaml/scanner.c -o scanner.o
gcc -DVERSION=\"git-5695363\" -Ilua-5.3/src -Ilibyaml/src/include -c ext/yaml/parser.c -o parser.o
gcc -DVERSION=\"git-5695363\" -Ilua-5.3/src -Ilibyaml/src/include -c ext/yaml/yaml.c -o yaml.o
```

Then linked:

```
gcc -shared -static -s -Llua-5.3/dist -Llibyaml/dist emitter.o parser.o scanner.o yaml.o -lyaml -llua53.dll -o lyaml.dll
```

I've linked it as `-shared` because the output is a dll and as `-static` because I'm statically linking libyaml.a. I also tried compiling with dynamic linking to libyaml.dll with the same error from Lua.

My Lua environment was compiled from the source and compiler:

```
> lua53.exe -v
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

Running a simple script works fine:

```
> lua53.exe -e 'print("Hello!")'
Hello!
```

But I can't load the library:

```
> lua53.exe -e 'require("lyaml")'
lua53.exe: error loading module 'lyaml' from file 'lyaml.dll':
        The specified procedure could not be found.

stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        (command line):1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

I know that this is an error from Windows but I don't know what procedure is missing or where it's coming from.

I also checked that all dynamic-linking dependencies are being met and functions are being exported:

[image]

How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up building everything on Linux and ran into the same problem but with a much more useful error:

```
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./test.lua
/bin/lua: error loading module 'lyaml' from file './lyaml.so':
        ./lyaml.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_lyaml
stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ./test.lua:5: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

The problem is that Lua binds the "luaopen_" symbol to the name of the library being loaded. So `require("somelib")` would be for `somelib.dll` with a an exact-matching `luaopen_somelib` export symbol. I built the library as `lyaml.dll` (to match the library name) but this symbol was exported as `luaopen_yaml`, which meant that Lua was looking for `luaopen_lyaml` (which didn't exist).

Several solutions are possible:

- Modify the export in the source code to match the file name.
- Modify the file name to match the export from the source code.
- Ignore the discrepancy completely and use `package.loadlib()` which allows this.

I've opted for the third solution. Thank you @PaulKulchenko for the third solution.

**The key takeaway from this is that there is by default a tight coupling between `require()`, the export symbol, and the file name of library being loaded.**

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Dependency walker, I recommend using its "Profile" feature. You can start profiling on `lua53.exe` file and when you execute the `require` command, the profiler will show you the trace of all DLLs being loaded and any errors related to their load as well as the details of the error that you don't see from the Lua message.

You can also execute `package.loadlib("lyaml.dll", "luaopen_yaml")` to confirm that the signature is valid; you should get a function back that, when executed, will return the actual package.

Comment: I didn't accept this for the answer because, while it did provide a good suggestion for debugging, I decided to write my own to detail the problem further with regards to the solution. I've given this an up-vote though because it was still helpful as the third option in my answer.

Comment: @Zhro, the solutions you listed are good, but, since you know what the problem is, I think a much easier solution is to configure `package.cpath` to load from `l?.dll`. For example, if you set `package.cpath="l?.dll"` and then use `require "yaml"`, everything should work without any modifications, as Lua loader will be checking for `luaopen_yaml` and that method is already present in the DLL.